# re.match returns false even when string pattern match

Tags: python, rematch

I am trying to match a pattern with the string, below is the code

```
bool(re.match('.._.. abc_xycompanies_........_._zip(001)','23_61 abc_xycompanies_20201212_1_zip(001)'))
```

The above code returns False, but if i change it to below then it is returning True. Dont know why but value inside the zip() is not getting matched.

```
bool(re.match('.._.. abc_xycompanies_........_._zip()','23_61 abc_xycompanies_20201212_1_zip()'))
```

How can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses have special meaning in regex, so you need to escape them in your case, to indicate you mean the specific parentheses *symbols*. Note:

```
>>> bool(re.match('zip\\(123\\)','zip(123)'))
True
```

P.S. Both your examples didn't match by me, so you might have some other issue as well.

Comment: Thanks it worked. P.S There was an issue with the code which i had pasted have corrected it